# SignalR Hub Issue - Restarting iis creates a new hub instance

Tags: asp.net, iis, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am using asp.Net SignalR Dependency injection technique for our implementation, so in our case, we have a hub constructor with one parameter.  I was wondering if there is a problem I have with the following, or is this how the system should react?

When I restart IIS, signalR will lose connection of course, and then come back online.  Afterwards, when it reconnects to our SignalR hub, it attempts to connect to the parameterless Hub constructor instead of the constructor with one parameter that is setup via the NinjectDependecnyResolver.  It seems to be trying to connect to the default Hub DependcyResolver after I restart IIS and signalR reconnects.  If I refresh the page after the IIS refresh, however, the paramaterized constructor is called, as it should be.

Does anyone know why my provided constructor is not fired after reconnecting to the SignalR hub after an IIS restart/IIS Stop-Start?

Comment: Maybe that's a problem with Ninject configuration? Also, have you tried to remove the parameterless constructor?

Comment: @qbik : Thanks for the input, I appreciate it.  It turns out the issue was with the ninject nancy bootstrapper, upon restart of the iis server, ninject does not initialize until the first page is requested, then app_start method is fired.  After a page is accessed for the first time, everything initializes correctly.  So I guess the only question left is if there is a way to fire that app_start event upon restarting the iis server without having to access a new page to fire it?